# how to add Eobject

Tags: python, java, eclipse

I'd like to create a function to add EObject. Previously I've created a function to check it.

```
import sys
def get_by_query_nam(e_obj, query_name, cls = None):
    e_object_class = getattr(sys.modules["__main__"], "EObject")
    return JavaList(getSBQuery(e_obj.get_java_object(), query_name), e_object_class)
```

this works as expected (using getName() to have the value name)

Now with the value from function  "get_by_query_name" I want to add another value to it.
Thanks !